# Synonym for 'removing unnecessary stuff'

Tags: phrases, synonyms

The synonym is used in the context:
"poor people are ________ from society through the new law"

p.s. this is not my political view but i have to write this sentence. Thanks all!

Comment: What exactly is meant by this? Poor people are given jobs so they are no longer poor? They are deported and sent to live somewhere else? They are killed? What is the broader context of the sentence? What have you already considered but rejected, and why?

Comment: eradicate? eliminate? suppress ?

Comment: Please provide some context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paring. Paring down.

*Society is **paring down** the population by ridding itself of the poor.*